# How to add a new column to extract a number/character from column 1 when column 2 reaches the max within each group?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-extraction, data-transform

I have 3 columns. C1 and C2 are grouped by C0. Now I want to extract the C3 value where it satisfies when C1 is maximum within each C0 group.

```
df = data.frame(C0 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
            C1 = c(0,2,3,6,2,0,0,4,9,7,1,2,7,4,2),
            C2 = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E","A","B", "C", "D", "E","A","B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

Now I want to add a new column C4, which is the value of C2 where the corresponding C1 reaches maximum within each C0 group. Now I can only extract the value of maximum C1, something like this

```
df %>% group_by(C0) %>% mutate (C4 = max(C1))
```

But this code returns as C4 is the value of the maximum value of C1 whitin each C0 group. I don't know how to extract the corresponding C2 value. Also, I don't want to just extract the row of the maximum value, but to add a new column. Like this (since I am not allowed to attach a figure, I am using the code to explain the idea:

```
df = data.frame(C0 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
            C1 = c(0,2,3,6,2,0,0,4,9,7,1,2,7,4,2),
            C2 = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E","A","B", "C", "D", "E","A","B", "C", "D", "E"),
            C4 = c("D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","C","C","C","C","C"))
```

Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `which.max` after grouping by 'C0' to get the row index and use that to subset the value of 'C2'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(C0) %>%
    mutate(C4 = C2[which.max(C1)])
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   C0 [3]
#      C0    C1 C2    C4   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
# 1     1     0 A     D    
# 2     1     2 B     D    
# 3     1     3 C     D    
# 4     1     6 D     D    
# 5     1     2 E     D    
# 6     2     0 A     D    
# 7     2     0 B     D    
# 8     2     4 C     D    
# 9     2     9 D     D    
#10     2     7 E     D    
#11     3     1 A     C    
#12     3     2 B     C    
#13     3     7 C     C    
#14     3     4 D     C    
#15     3     2 E     C
```